# How to select using CONTAINS instead of LIKE with JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.1, postgresql-13, java-15

I'm developing small java applications to school projects with PostgreSQL.

Using the JDBC driver I could select a field using the `~` operator to act as `CONTAINING` instead of concatenating the filter using `LIKE`.

Let me give you an example:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME ~ ? ORDER BY NAME
```

Since we started using the JPA framework to ease the development, I noticed that the same sample using JPA throws an error when I use the `~` operator...

Error thrown:

```
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select u from Users u where u.name ~ ?1 order by u.name]. 
[30, 41] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

All code samples I could find on google are made using `LIKE` instead of `CONTAINING`.

My question is, does JPA support the containing operator when working with PostgreSQL?

Some info:

```
JDK 15
Netbeans 12.3
JPA 2.1
PostgreSQL 13.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct because `jpa` does not support the `~` operator, for further informations you can check the [persistence-2_1](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) oracle link containing the `jpa` pdf specification with the list of all available `jpa` operators *not* including the `~` operator.
The comparison  operators available are just the following:  *=, >, >=, <, <=, <>  (not  equal),  [NOT]BETWEEN, [NOT]LIKE,[NOT]IN, IS[NOT]NULL,  IS[NOT]EMPTY, [NOT]MEMBER[OF], [NOT]EXISTS*

Comment: A shame really, contains is so much easier to use, can select stuff with blank parameters and etc. but thanks for the answer!

Comment: @NickolasDeluca You are welcome, unfortunately you have only two alternatives :  use one native query missing jpql advantages  or rewrite your original query with just these operators if possible.

Comment: No need to stress over it, completely possible to rewrite to use LIKE, it's only less desirable.

Comment: @NickolasDeluca Completely agree with you.